# Send a notification email when someone leaves a comment in Facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, api, sdk

How do I send a notifiaction email when someone leave a comment in Facebook comments plugin.

I have this script but any time someone comes to my page I get an email.

I only want to get an email when a new user comments on the page

```
<script> window.fbAsyncInit = function() {



    FB.init({
      appId      : 'appid', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//http://www.corkdiscos.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


FB.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
  <?php   
 $to      = 'info@a2bdjs.com';
 $subject = 'Comment Posted on Testimonial Page';
 $message = 'Comment Posted on Testimonial Page';
 $headers = 'From: info@a2bdjs.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: info@a2bdjs.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();   
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
});

};


  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make an ajax call in the following manner.

```
/* Get FB comment notification */
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
            var data = {
                action: 'fb_comment',
                url: response
            };

            $.post( '`URL TO THE PHP FILE CONTAINING THE MAIL CODE`', data );
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then put the following in the above specified php file.

```
<?php   
 if ( isset( $_POST['url'] ) ) {
     $to      = 'info@a2bdjs.com';
     $subject = 'Comment Posted on Testimonial Page';
     $message = 'Comment Posted on Testimonial Page';
     $headers = 'From: info@a2bdjs.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@a2bdjs.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();   
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

You could run a few more checks to be on the safer side.

Answer (score 0):

You have something weird going on there.  You are placing server-side code (PHP) inside client-side code(Javascript) .  The PHP code will be executed on your server, so you'll have to place that code in a separate file and make an AJAX call (with JavaScript), to that file, which will execute the PHP code and send the mail.

Get rid of that PHP code inside the `FB.Subscribe` function, put this instead :

```
FB.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
    if(typeof console != 'undefined') {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Then open up the console (F12 in Chrome for the developers tools, or with firebug on firefox).
Take a look at the `response` variable and you'll be able to see what type of event has happened.

Comment: iv updated my webpage with the above code. http://corkdiscos.com/testimonials.html what am i looking for in the console.log ??